# JDBC parsing int from SQL query

Tags: java, mysql, string, servlets, jdbc

I am pretty new to programming in Java and am having a little difficulty. I have searched around but could not get an exact answer for what I am trying to do.

Basically, I have created a 3-tier application that uses servlets running on a server to access a mySQL database using JDBC.

For the most part, my application runs fine. I am able to run my queries and display my results.

The problem is, I need to implement some logic based on my query, which is a String.

For example,

ex1_query: `insert into parts values ('S5', 'P6', 'J7', 50);`

ex2_query: `insert into parts values ('S5', 'P6', 'J7', 400);`

My queries are being submitted through an HTML form as single string. As you can see, the only difference between ex1_query and ex2_query is their last value (50 & 400).

The logic is, that if that last value is >=100, I need to implement some stuff…

If that value is <100, just run the query as specified.

My queries will always be entered in that format, but that last value may vary from 0 - 1000.

So my question is… how can I parse just that last int from the string? So I can determine whether I should or should not implement some specific logic?

I know it sounds pretty simple, but I am having a little trouble. Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You do not have any control on the generation of these query strings ? So you have to parse the value out ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html - this would be a good starting point.

Comment: Well, I am guaranteed they are being entered in that format. I basically have a series of commands I copy and paste into my form, and then execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But If you don't wanted to go with  `Preparedstatement`

then here is one more option

```
    String ex1_query = "insert into parts values ('S5', 'P6', 'J7', 50);";

    String lastValue = ex1_query.substring( ex1_query.lastIndexOf(",")+1, ex1_query.lastIndexOf(")")).trim();

 Integer lastNumber = null;
        try {
            lastNumber = Integer.parseInt(lastValue);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // if last value is not int then handle here 
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        if(lastNumber >=100){

        }
```

In lastValue you can get 50/400 or any value and do your stuff

Comment: Thank you, both of your answers were very helpful. I think this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

User Prepared Statement

```
 String param1= "S5";
  String param2= "p6";
  String param3= "j7"; 
  int param4= 50 0r 400  ; 

 public void someMethod(String param1,String param2,String param3,String param4){

if(param4 >= 100){
//your stuff
param4 =  ; //your new value;
}

query =  insert into parts values (?, ?, ?,?);
```

And Execute your Query

Comment: Thanks, that helps. But I would now have to worry about parsing my entire string into different parameters. Is there no other way just to get that last value?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have any control about the query you might want to befriend [java.util.regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html) and parse for something like:

```
"^\s*insert\s+into\s+([A-Za-z0-9]+)\s+values\s+\(\s*('\w+'\s*,\s*){3}([0-9]+)\)\s*$"
```

This is actually an old-style grep regex but a regex with the same function is possible for java.util.regex. It checks whether the string follows your pattern. submatch #1 should give you your table name. submatch #2-#4 should give you the values 1-3 and submatch #5 contains the number (as  string of course) you're looking for. Also a nice way to reject queries you do not like.

Answer (score 0):

If your query will remain same except that `integer` value, you can use `substring`.

```
String query = "insert into parts values ('S5', 'P6', 'J7', 50);"
int value = Integer.parseInt(query.substring(43, query.length()-2));
```

Or you can use regular expression to accomplish this.

```
String query = "insert into parts values ('S5', 'P6', 'J7', 50);";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=(.+,\\s?))(\\d+)(?=(\\);))");
int value = Integer.parseInt(pattern.matcher(query).group());
```